# Why no ooVoo on ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation

The only reason I ever boot into Windows (7) is to use the popular video chat software ooVoo ([website](http://oovoo.com)). It's useless under Wine and there seems to be no way to run it in Ubuntu except for some proprietary tools. Does anyone have any information on some alternatives to running it with Wine?

Comment: alternative being things like skype? or many mainstream messenger client?

Comment: no as in different ways to run the oovoo software inside linux

Comment: Oh man, its too bad ooVoo requires Windows to be installed for the mac version :) Sorry was a funny typo on the site.

Comment: you can use web video feature in oovoo and you don't need to install oovoo on ubuntu .
check this out: http://www.oovoo.com/HowToooVooItem.aspx?pname=HowToooVooWebVideoCall You can have a video call with your AIM or Facebook friends - just send them the Web Video Call link from the chat window.
Your family member, friend or business contact hasn't downloaded ooVoo yet - send them the Web Video Call link through email.
You want someone to quickly video call you.

Answer (score 7):

[Ekiga](http://ekiga.org/) - free(gratis), free(libre)

[QuteCom](http://www.qutecom.org/) - free(gratis), free(libre)

[Skype](http://www.skype.com/intl/en-gb/home) - free(gratis), non-free(libre)

*To find this I searched 'voip', 'video chat' and 'softphone' (seperately) in the Ubuntu Software Centre (I already knew about Skype)*

Comment: Skype is free - but outbound land-line calls are not.

Comment: Also. Google Video chat works well in Empathy.

Comment: @Marco Ceppi Skype is not free, it is gratis ;) Free as in freedom it is not!

Answer (score 2):

After some Google Searching and some unsuccessful fiddling around with Wine  I decided to search for an alternative. That is When I found Tokbox! Tokbox is A FREE Cloud based alternative to ooVoo for Ubuntu Linux user has just been released.

No need for wine or a Virtual Box and thier is nothing to Download. Tokbox is a website that brings video conferencing into the cloud. What does than mean for you? It will work on any computer that has a web browser and Adobe Flash installed. That means that literally everyone out know can use it and the best part it works INSTANTLY.

Just send them a link through facebook, twitter, Aim, Google Talk or even an email and they can connect this you in a matter of seconds. Take that ooVoo and their is no need for the recipient for the invitation to sign up either. Simply click the link and you are inside a live video conference. I will be installing a Web App using Google Chrome today on all the computers in the Internet cafe today and their will be a big shinny icon on everyones desktop pointing to the TokBox App on everyones home screen. For more information Visit http://www.tokbox.com/ Enjoy.

Comment: If you're going to copy and paste answers from somewhere else, you should always [credit the source](http://addicted-2-retail.com/oovoo-for-ubuntu-free-linux-alternative/).

Comment: They are going to stop this service as of April 2011, check this link for more info on this. http://me.tokbox.com/

Answer (score 1):

I use Google hangouts... It's rock solid and stable (never crashes. Even if your internet stops working and then starts working again, you can re-enter the video conference call! Really cool) It's free, up to ten people in the same video call (I think it's ten) It's backed up by the bigegst company in the world... So why not give it a try. I am happy with it... Oh BTW... It has its own mobile app too!

Answer (score 0):

[Empathy](http://live.gnome.org/Empathy) does video calls for some of the protocols it support, and maybe [aMSN](http://www.amsn-project.net/) ([install](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/amsn)) Messenger® video chat, but it's not good to depend on a proprietary protocol that may change without warning.

Comment: Actually, aMSN no longer provides video chat on the WLM protocol, because of some changes made by Microsoft. At least that was the case a few months ago.

Answer (score 0):

Pidgin now supports video calls over Jabber (XMPP)