# FOSS Conference calling software

Tags: sound, skype, voip

I have so far been using Skype to do conference calls on Ubuntu Maverick. I want to stop using Skype because the client looks pretty bad (or has a number of minor bugs) in the default Ubuntu theme (e.g. menu items don't display unless you point at them), and it seems to use up a lot of my CPU while audio calling.

Are there any audio conferencing (i.e. 2-10 people in a call simultaneously) tools that are FOSS and work quite well in Ubuntu?

EDIT:

**Some additional requirements:**
1) I want to have minimal setup and use open protocols if possible.
2) I need a s/w feature to record the call (I'm planning to make podcasts).
3) Cross platform - The people I call may be on a difference OS, so a suitable client should be available for their system too (Win/Mac).

Comment: Answers to [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/1801/667) may help you.

Comment: As for the menu items not showing unless you point at them: Open Skype options and choose style "Desktop Settings" or "GTK+".

Comment: @Lightbreeze - Thanks for that tip! At least skype looks better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Ekiga*** ( http://ekiga.org/ ), quoting from the website:

> **Ekiga** (formely known as GnomeMeeting) is an open source SoftPhone, **Video Conferencing** and Instant Messenger application over the Internet.
>   It supports HD sound quality and video up to DVD size and quality.
>   It is interoperable with many other standard compliant softwares, hardwares and service providers as it uses both the major telephony standards (SIP and H.323).

[image]

It is Gnome software so well-integrated with your Ubuntu desktop and has all the features you need. Try it :)

Comment: Open protocols, conference calling - works fine for me. But there is no facility to record a call yet. Looks like this is the nearest I am going to get. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed no call recording feature for Ekiga yet, but it is something already discussed: https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=330276. However someone managed to record a voip call ( maybe a little bit complicated ). Look here: http://www.nuxified.org/blog/recording_your_ekiga_calls_with_wireshark

Answer (score 2):

Actually, we use this thing called "mumble" inside Canonical. It's organized
like an IRC server with various rooms and basic texting ability. Great
for ad hoc meetings and a little more entertaining than just hanging out
on IRC. The configuration could be better, but once you get the mic setup
right, and settle on your push to talk keys, you're pretty much all set.

https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mumble/1.1.8-3

Comment: Mumble seems to require a mumble-server to be setup.

Comment: @donatello You should update your question with more detail specifying what your requirements are so people can get you more detailed answers.