# How to install ooVoo on ubuntu 12.04 64 bit

Tags: 12.04, installation, wine, winetricks, instant-messaging

kindly help to install ooVoo in Ubuntu 12.04 64 bit.

Comment: Obviously is not working properly
http://askubuntu.com/questions/1801/why-no-oovoo-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 2):

OOVOO currently only have version for Mac and PC.  To run it in Ubuntu, you need Wine.

Wine allows you to run Windows applications on a Linux operating system. For more information on Wine check their [Website](http://www.winehq.org/). You can install Wine from the Ubuntu Software Center.

Also you may want to check out [OpenTok](http://www.tokbox.com/industries).  Its the Linux alternative to OOVOO.

Comment: Does not work on wine 1.9

Comment: @BhikkhuSubhuti I haven't tried it,  but I don't see why not.  I would recommend the latest release of OOVOO

Comment: Don't comment (and possibly down vote me) if you have not tried it.  I did.  It does not work and there is a link on wine hq that says it installs (true) but does not work when you you try to use it to log in or anything else (true).. and all is still true as of today.  Please have some etiquette.

Comment: Open Tok is for professionals and charges money LOTS of money.  Do not bother to go the website as I did